# Get user id from url php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Hi there i'm trying to get **data-id** from url and use this id to insert into database, to make like dislike system.

**data-id="1"** it is user id.

The link look like this:

```
<a data-fav="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['favorite']; ?>" data-fav-active="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['favorited']; ?>" class="favorite favoriteIcon" data="<?php echo $key['id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $key['user_id']; ?>" data-token="<?php echo $key['token_id']; ?>">
```

**PHP source**

### some more information: the link is inside of the message that users write,  when someone clicks **like message**, it goes to function call **favorites**

```
public function favorites() {
    /*
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *  Add, Remove Favorites
     * @$active  :"Check to see if the user has already added prior to Favourites"
     * @verified : "Check if the publication exists"
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    $active   = self :: favsUser( null, $_SESSION['authenticated'], $_POST['id'] );
    $verified = self :: checkPost( $_POST['id'], $_POST['token'] ) ? 1 : 0;


    if( $verified == 1 && empty( $active ) )
    {
        $_idPost  = (int)$_POST['id'];
        $_sql     = $this->db->prepare("SELECT user FROM posts WHERE id = :id");
        $_sql->execute( array(  
                            ':id' => $_idPost 
                            ) 
                        );
        $response = $_sql->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

        /** If not exists, insert new record  **/
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO favorites VALUES( null, ?, ?, '1', '".$this->_dateNow."' );");
        $sql->bindValue( 1, $_GET['data-id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $sql->bindValue( 2, $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $sql->execute();
        if( $sql->rowCount() !=  0 ) {

            if( $response->user != $_SESSION['authenticated'] ) {
                /* Send Interaction */
            self :: sendInteraction( $response->user, $_SESSION['authenticated'], $_idPost, 3 );    
            }
            return( 1 );
        }

    }

    if( $verified == 1 && !empty( $active ) && $active[0]['status'] == '1' )
    {
        /** If exists, update status to Delete/Trash  **/
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE favorites SET status = '0' WHERE id_usr = ? && id_favorite = ? ");
        $sql->bindValue( 1, $_SESSION['authenticated'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $sql->bindValue( 2, $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $sql->execute();
        if( $sql->rowCount() !=  0 )
        {
            return( 2 );
        }
    }
    else if ( $verified == 1 && !empty( $active ) && $active[0]['status'] == '0' )
        {
            /** If exists and status == Delete/Trash, update status to Active  **/
            $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE favorites SET status = '1' WHERE id_usr = ? && id_favorite = ? ");
            $sql->bindValue( 1, $_SESSION['authenticated'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $sql->bindValue( 2, $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $sql->execute();
        if( $sql->rowCount() !=  0 )
        {
            return( 3 );
        }
    }
        return false;
        $this->db = null;

   }
```

**MYSQL starcture**

TABLE **favorites**

COLUMNS: **id** (automatic), **id_usr** (user id from data-id that we need to take from url ), **id_post** (if of post all set), **date** (date)

**Thank you.**

Comment: you have to pass the data-id in the URL. have a jQuery event or custom  javascript that appends this value to the URL. if you are doing a POST, then i recommend to have this as a hidden value in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the URL parameter **data-id**, but you never refer to it in your code.  Just use `$_GET['data-id']`.

EDIT: Now that I'm looking at your question more closely, I think you're actually asking a question about doing it with JavaScript using AJAX.  If that's the case, I strongly recommend you use jQuery.  Then, you just retrieve the id with something like what I have at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk2eg/).

If you want the link to actually work as a clickable link, you need to change it like this:

```
<a data-fav="like" data-block-active="like" class="block" data="21" data-id="1" data-token="e6fcbe9adff7764872b8b9a571848084e36cf72a" href="?data-id=1">foo bar text goes here...</a>
```

Then, you could actually use `$_GET['data-id']` in your PHP code.

Comment: There's no URL or href attribute, so there won't be a GET param I don't think.

Comment: i have tried like this:

$sql->bindValue( 1, $_GET['data-id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$sql->bindValue( 2, $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );

Did not work

Comment: all i need is just grab this id and put it in database even with jquery i have to grab it too.

Comment: i'm trying ll let u know

Comment: unfortunately mysql could not grab the id.

i did:

`<a href="?data-id=<?php echo $key['user_id']; ?>" data-fav="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['favorite']; ?>" data-fav-active="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['favorited']; ?>" class="favorite favoriteIcon" data="<?php echo $key['id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $key['user_id']; ?>" data-token="<?php echo $key['token_id']; ?>">`

----------------------

$sql->bindValue( 1, $_GET['data-id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$sql->bindValue( 2, $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );

Comment: the script taking $_POST['id'] no problem but when it gets to data-id it stacked. FWY  $_POST['id'] is **data="21"**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "mysql could not grab the id."  How are you getting the data to your PHP script?  `$_GET['data-id']` will only be set if there is a `data-id` parameter in the URL (i.e., if somebody clicked on the link you are creating above).

Comment: well data-id is in a link, i think there is a mistake in php script but i can not find it.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about whether data-id is ever being passed to your script.  There is a `data-id="blah"` parameter in an `<a>` tag, but that is not the same as a data-id parameter in the URL of the page.  PHP can't "see" the HTML output that the user sees; it only knows what "data-id" is if `$_POST` or `$_GET` contains a `data-id` value.  In other words, `$_GET['data-id']` doesn't exist unless your user visits http://yoursite.whatever/somepage?data-id=something.

Comment: i've tried a lot of ways i'm just out of ideas how to implement this.

Comment: Does your user ever visit a page like yoursite.whatever/somepage?data-id=something? If so, use $_GET.  If not, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it is going to involve AJAX.  If you can provide more information about how data-id is supposed to get to your server, then people can help you.  As it is, it's still not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($_GET)` and see what happens.  You clearly are not getting to a page with data-id in the $_GET array.

Comment: what about $HTTP_GET_VARS["data-id"]; ?

Comment: @user2990788: I'm giving up on this. $HTTP_GET_VARS is deprecated.  You aren't providing necessary information to demonstrate that you are ever sending the user to a page where data-id is a parameter.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you actually click on the "anchor tag link" what is the url that you see?